# I want to write a formula in Google Sheets that counts the appearance of a value in a range, but the range is the result of another formula

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm trying to count the number of times "Tuesday" (or any day of the week) appears in a range. However, my range is another formula, that is, the "Tuesday" is the result of a formula from another cell where I have put in the date.

For example, in B1, I have put in "2019.09.17." Thus, A1 will show, "Tuesday" because I set A1 to show the day of the week that corresponds to the date in B1.

If it matters, my formula in A1 is just "=B1" and then I changed the "Format>Number" to display just the day of the week.

My actual range is A1:A10.

I've tried `=countif(A1:A10,"Tuesday")`, but the result returns 0. I've also tried `=countif(B1:B10,"Monday")` to try and use the range from the "original" input, but the result is still 0.

Sorry if this question has been asked elsewhere and I'll be more than happy to rescind my question and read the answer elsewhere if someone could just direct me to it because I'm also actually not sure how to search for what I'm asking.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To get the "day of the week" you can use the following formula:

=TEXT(B1,"ddddd")

and then `count` normally "

Hope this helps!

Sidney

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF(TO_TEXT(A1:A10), A12))
```

[image]